# displaying webpages every few seconds, for webpages that can't load in a frame?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, iframe, frame

I want to create a web page to display amazon products (kiosk-like display) and the goal is to change to the next product every few seconds. Amazon pages can't load in frames, so using php (or any client side/server side solution) is there a way to set a timer to change to the next product?
Here is the sequence:

Show product 1 -----> show product 2 ----> show product 3 ----> repeat

Here is a simple code that uses frames but it doesn't load amazon in the frame. My next step was to add timer but first I need to figure out how I can show amazon pages in a fashion that I can move to the next one after a few seconds. Basically the issue is that without the frames how can I set a timer (either server side or client side) to redirect the page to the next product?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="500" height="400" id="myFrame" src="http://www.amazon.com"></iframe>

<p>Click the button to change the value of the src attribute in the iframe.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "http://www.amazon.com";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is never going work .. time for plan B

Comment: @Dagon oh no! that's what I was afraid of. Any hint for plan B? chrome extensions maybe?

Comment: other than breaching amazons terms of service, i'm not sure what your trying to do, so can't really say.

Comment: You may be able to figure out how to use one of the Amazon [widget codes](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/help/t22/a3%3Fie%3DUTF8%26pf_rd_m%3D..%26pf_rd_t%3D501) to make it reload with a different product after a certain amount of time. At least that's where I would start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Coding method (javascript and popup window):**

I was able to do this with a pop up window instead of frames. Basically what you need to do is to open a pop up and control the url of that pop up through the parent page. Here is a sample code of the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>   
window.setInterval(function(){
  process();
}, 15000);

arr = ['http://www.amazon.com/Apple-AirPort-Express-Station-MC414LL/dp/B008ALA2RC', 
       'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0087NZ31S'
      ];

var popup = window.open('http://www.amazon.com','rotator');

i = 0;
function process(){
      i++;
      index =i%arr.length;
      popup.location.href=arr[index];
}   
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Browser extension method:**

I found a chrome extension named [Rotisserie URL Rotator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZp9L2suTMAhUM1oMKHZ3EA-4QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Frotisserie-url-rotator%2Filjemanjjfjlglhkmojkmfbpphiaheja%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNGrAntzn4ufTquCSCzWa_CRJojM7w) that does the rotation, can set a time for each page in seconds. Basically you will specify a set of (url, time) tuples and it will rotate on those urls for the specified times. I also found a few more but for now this does job for the display purpose well. I also found one that will rotate between tabs and had a lot more features like specifying random times, etc. But my main purpose was to show the page in only one tab.